# ¿Por qué usamos el término redundante "arco iris" en español?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

En español, el término correcto para designar al "fenómeno óptico que presenta en forma de arco de bandas concéntricas los siete colores elementales, causado por la refracción o reflexión de la luz solar en el agua pulverizada, generalmente perceptible en la lluvia" es *[arco iris](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3TE56ZB#4Kix0xA)* o *[arcoíris](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3TGhZfI)*.

Resulta que la palabra que se usaba en latín para referirse a este fenómemo era sencillamente... *iris*. Y de hecho esto se ve aún en el DLE.

> [**iris**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M6Smp06)
>
> Del lat. *iris*, y este del gr. *ἶρις îris*.
>
> 1. m. arco iris.

Consultando algunos diccionarios antiguos, veo por ejemplo que el de Nebrija de 1495 recoge la entrada *arco del cielo*, Covarrubias en 1611 lo recoge como *arco celeste*, y el *Diccionario de Autoridades* recoge *arco iris* pero redirige a *iris*, donde se encuentra la definición de este fenómeno atmosférico.

Y, sin embargo, el término que ha acabado imponiéndose es *arco iris*, redundante dado que solamente *iris* ya recoge toda la idea del fenómeno. Al parecer en portugués y gallego también ocurre, pero en otros idiomas cercanos no:

- arc de Sant Martí (catalán),
- arcobaleno (italiano),
- arc-en-ciel (francés).

¿Cómo evolucionó el idioma para que pasáramos de una expresión similar a la del francés (arco celestial) a una redundante (arco iris)?

> *Et como la ora vn cercol a semblança de arco celestial aparecio en torno del sol.*
>
> Juan Fernández de Heredia, "Traducción de Breviarium ab urbe condita, de Eutropio.", 1377-1399 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Arcum dizian los latinos una yerva: cuya flor enla variedad del color pareçe al arco celestial.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

Comment: En la actualidad _Iris_ se usa más para la parte de color de los ojos. Si siguiéramos usando esa palabra para el arco iris tendríamos que haber inventado otra para los ojos.

Comment: Estoy con @DGaleano, *iris* tenía varios significados, solo uno de los cuales era *arco iris*. Además del significado de para los ojos, también se podría y se puede hablar de la *piedra iris*, hoy conocido como *iris* a secas u *ópalo noble*; o bien la *planta iris*, que tienen flores de una multitud de colores; el *color iris*, que es un tipo de púrpura.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es común encontrar frases que contengan palabras redundantes. Estos tipos de frases/términos se llaman [*pleonasmos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo). Unos ejemplos fosilizados son *conmigo* y *desde*:

- *me* + *cum* → *mecum* → *micu(m)* → *migo* → ***con*** + *mi**go*** → *conmigo*
- ***de*** + ***ex*** → *dēex* → *des* → ***de***s + ***de*** → *desde*

No obstante, ver la ortografía de los cognados de la frase en otros idiomas romances:

- `Catalan` [*arc iris*](https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/arc_iris) <sup>lit.</sup>, *arc d'Iris* (galicismo) <sup>lit.</sup>
- `Francés` [*arc d'Iris*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arc-en-ciel) <sup>lit.</sup>
- `Portugués` *arco-íris*
- `Asturiano` *arcu iris, arcu de iris, arcu d'iris*

podemos entender que la parte 'iris' de 'arcoíris' no viene directamente del griego ἶρις (*iris*), que significa el fenómeno atmosférico, **sino via el nombre de la diosa del fenómeno,  [Ἶρῐς](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(mitolog%C3%ADa)) (*Iris*).**

Las alternativas ortografías antiguas castellanas *«arco de Iris»* y *«arco Iris»* (con mayúscula) parece confirmar esto:

> ... lido de mi largo penar, parece que ha mostrado su **arco de Iris**, aplacando mis borrascas...
>
> - *Historias peregrinas y ejemplares*, Gonzalo de Céspedes y Meneses (1623)

> ... al arnor, el amar al aborrecer; a la tempestad el **arco Iris**, a la tormenta, bonança...
>
> - *Epítome de las fábulas de la antigüedad*, Juan de Piña (1635)

Y finalmente, este ensayo también afirma que el nombre viene de la diosa:

> Es muy antigua la creencia de que ciertos “agentes mágicos” eran los responsables del tiempo atmosférico, empezando por ejemplo por la nominación misma del arco iris...<sup>1</sup>
>
> - [*Contraste entre unidades fraseológicas españolas e italianas - sobre fobias y supersticiones*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/paremia/pdf/016/007_arribas.pdf), Nieves Arribas Esteras (2007)

---

---

**Notas:**

1. > <sup><sup>En español se dice: “Cuando llueve y hace sol, sale el arco del Señor; cuando llueve y hace sol saca el cuerno el caracol”; “Algún diablo se ha casado”; “Algún diablo anda suelto”. En algunas zonas de Italia, al ver el arco iris la gente decía: *il diavolo va a bere*. No sólo el ámbito de la fraseología sino también el de la propia nominación del arco iris constituye un caso muy particular en toda Europa pues conforma un abanico de imágenes misteriosas donde conviven lo pagano y lo cristiano en sucesivos estratos solapados unos a otros y cuyas raíces se hunden en la más remota prehistoria. Pueden distinguirse varios ciclos nominativos respecto a este fenómeno: los más antiguos, con un determinante perteneciente a alguna parte del cuerpo (llamados por ello somatismos) ya sea de un dios, de una diosa o de un monstruo, constituyen otra esfera semántica muy productiva para denominar el arco iris, (“serpiente de la lluvia”, “gusano de agua”, “cintura de la vieja”, “cintura de la monja”…); un segundo ciclo también somático pero en el que los atributos corporales se refieren a santos (“cintura de Santa Elena”, “cinturón de la Virgen”…) y un tercer ciclo que subraya el hecho de poner en contacto dos  mundos, con determinantes como “arco”, “puente”, “escala”, “puerta” (“alianza de Noé”, “arco del Señor”, “arco (de) Iris /arcoiris”, “puente de San Miguel”…)</sup></sup>

Por interés, otros nombres regionales<sup>[1](http://www.diariodeleon.es/noticias/revista/arcu-vieya_1065813.html) [2](http://www.dialettando.com/dizionario/hitlist_new.lasso?saltarec=0&results_curpage=1&parola=arcobaleno&campo=Italiano)</sup>:

[image]

[image: !enter image description here]

Comment: "Ya el cielo, condolido de mi largo penar, parece que ha mostrado su arco de Iris, aplacando mis borrascas, de suerte que de las mismas vuestras haya nacido la paz que mi alma ha deseado." Este texto se escribió en España en 1623, y corrobora lo que comentas. Aunque he encontrado también un texto de Perú de 1572 que menciona "subidos a la cumbre, vieron en ella el arco iris del cielo", que no sé cómo encaja en la evolución del término.

Comment: La expresión "arco de Iris" parece que solo aparece en algunos textos del siglo XVII, y se ve que antes de eso ya se usaba "arco iris". Entre eso y que "iris" de por sí hacía mención al fenómeno además de a la diosa, tengo mis dudas de que el "iris" en la expresión actual se refiera a ella. De hecho en la imagen que has adjuntado menciona que el español "arco iris" viene de "iris" como "rainbow".

Comment: [La fuente de la imagen](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymologymaps/comments/6j8av1/etymology_of_the_word_rainbow/) es solo lo que dice en Wiktionary sin más investigación, no es muy meticuloso. Sin embargo, el nombre de la diosa [viene de la palabra griega antigua del fenómeno](http://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Iris.html) *sí mismo*: `ἶρις > Ἶρῐς` y por eso, en cualquier caso, tiene razón.

Comment: no creo que arcoiris o arco iris sea un pleonasmo 
ya que el iris tambien puede ser el de los ojos